# How to Delete Selected Row in DatagridView and Ms Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to delete row in datagridviw view and also in MS access database, but i have some errors.

Here is my code:

```
     'Dim myDataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
     'Dim myDataTable As DataTable
    myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)
    ZoznamBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ZoznamBindingSource

    ZoznamBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()

    myDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable)

    Private Sub Datagridviewupadtae()
    Dim objDS As New DataSet
    Dim objDT As New DataTable
    objDS.Tables.Add(objDT)
    Dim objConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = 
    F:\Password manager\Password Database\Database.accdb"
    conn.ConnectionString = objConn
    Dim objDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Zoznam", conn)
    objDA.Fill(objDT)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = objDT.DefaultView
    End Sub
```

Now i am gettitng an error myDataAdapter = Nothing

Do someone know what i do bad?

Comment: What kind of errors ? We cannot guess your problem with so little information. It would also be good to show the code for the binding source, datatable etc so we can see how the datagrid is actually being populated.

Comment: You keep asking this question and keeps being answered and you keep ignoring the answers. For the third time, DO NOT do ANYTHING with the grid. You should have already used a data adapter to populate a `DataTable`, bound that to a `BindingSource` and bound that to the grid. As you have been told repeatedly. the ONLY thing you need to do to flag the current row from the grid is to call `RemoveCurrent` on the `BindingSource`. Once you have made all the changes you are going to make, then call `Update` on the data adapter to save those changes to the database. Do what you've been told for once.

Comment: I also see that, on at least one occasion, someone has provided you with an answer that solved another issue you had and you haven't accepted their answer. That means they don't get credit for it and no one can see that the question has been answered without wasting time opening and reading the thread. Why would anyone want to help you at this stage if you refuse to follow the rules of the site and you ignore information when it's provided?

Comment: Also, where did anyone tell you to do this: `ZoznamBindingSource.DataSource = DataGridView1`? What do you think that is accomplishing?

Comment: @jmcilhinney No, I am not trying to ignore people answers, I just do't get it. I am a beginner and understanding what people answers is not for me so clear for me.

Comment: `ZoznamBindingSource.DataSource = DataGridView1`  I tought that was updating DataGridView. I get it from one web site. I'm so desperate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I've already answered basically the same question multiple times, I will try once more in the hope that something actually sinks in this time. You get the data like this:

```vb
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource
```

You delete the current row in the grid like this:

```vb
myBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
```

You save the changes like this:

```vb
myDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable)
```

Obviously you need to configure the data adapter with appropriate commands but that is not directly relevant to the question of deleting a record from a grid. There's no changing of data sources and there's no touching the grid. Please actually do what you've been told this time.

Comment: I did your procedure, but i got an error: myDataAdapter was Nothing. Should I have done something other than the above code?

Comment: If your data adapter variable is `Nothing` then that means that you have never assigned a data adapter to it. This is not something that we should need to explain. If we tell you that you need to use an object of type X then it should simply be assumed that you need to create an object of type X because it is programming 101. If you don't understand the basics of programming then you should stop what you're doing and work through a beginners tutorial or two because it's not our job to teach you those fundamentals.